# How loop through all rows of a jtable

Tags: java, arrays, swing, for-loop, jtable

I'm trying to loop through all of the rows in a column in a jTable at the moment I can get it to loop through a column but it only gives me the first 5 values and it also gives me a strange output.

here is the code:

```
private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        // Button to Start
    Object[] columnData = new Object[jTable1.getColumnCount()];
    Object[] rowData = new Object [jTable1.getRowCount()];
    for (int i = 0; i < jTable1.getColumnCount(); i++) {
    columnData[i] = jTable1.getValueAt(i, 4);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(columnData));
    }
```

here is the output:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are using your column iteration as the row number in your code.  `jTable1.getValue(i, 4)` has parameters row, column in that order. If you only have five columns, you will only get five values.

Try changing the loop to count through the rows and select the 5th column.

```
private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    // Button to Start
    Object[] columnData = new Object[jTable1.getRowCount()];  // One entry for each row
    Object[] rowData = new Object [jTable1.getRowCount()];
    for (int i = 0; i < jTable1.getRowCount(); i++) {  // Loop through the rows
        // Record the 5th column value (index 4)
        columnData[i] = jTable1.getValueAt(i, 4);  
     }
     System.out.println(Arrays.toString(columnData));
```

Comment: yes is what I'm trying to do. Also to get it to stop showing the null values do i need to add a 'emptyRowFlag'

Comment: When you print out the columnData array as a string, you'll get all the data, including the null values.  If you only want to see the last value, you could do `System.out.println(columnData[i])` within the loop, or wait until the loop is finished and print the whole array at once.

Comment: this does not work as it is looking for a class called i

Comment: You have to put that inside the loop where "i" is defined.  Outside the loop you just refer to columnData as in the code in my answer above.